What kind of via, or pad is this?
All I can tell that it carries some of the paths from the top layer to the bottom layer for the edge connector. How do I reproduce this?


What material is it even? How thick? What's around it? I don't have a sense of space here, it just looks like an abstract figure evoking technology.

@TimWilliams
.2mm thick, its a 2 layer transparent flex pcb.
The 10-19th wires go from the top layer to the bottom layer through whatever the black part is, trying to figure out what the black part is and how to recreate it

Have to have more context to know what this is. Or what kind of process was used a picture probably isn't going to do it. It looks like it could just be coverlay over the soldered junction but who knows?
